# Is it possible to use ES6 Symbols in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local-storage

When using a ES6 `Symbol` as the key for a key/value pair in `LocalStorage`, can we then still access it after reloading the page?

I found [this tutorial](https://starbeamrainbowlabs.com/blog/article.php?article=posts/92-ES6-Symbols.html) that claims this to be possible when using `Symbol.for`, but so far I have no success and get an `undefined` when I try to retrieve the LocalStorage key/value pair.

As a side question: does it make sense to use `Symbols` over here?

Comment: Can you share an example where it is not working? For example, on jsbin.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Symbols as keys in an object - that's one of theirs purposes. But `localStorage` is not your typical object. It has an API to set/get values in the store, which the tutorial you have shared is not using: `localStorage.{set,get}Item()`.

Unfortunately `localStorage` doesn't accept Symbols as keys, only strings. So the real answer is no, you can't use Symbols as keys in LocalStorage, but...

You *could* do the following. It isn't actually using a Symbol as the key, but the Symbols `toString()` representation:

```
const sym = Symbol.for('Hello').toString()
localStorage.setItem(sym, 'World')
document.write('Hello, ' + localStorage.getItem(sym))
```

[ [Check it out on jsbin.com](https://sdgluck.jsbin.com/dabucel/edit?html,js,console,output) ]

> As a side question: does it make sense to use Symbols over here?

I suppose you could use reserved Symbols (e.g. `Symbol.iterator`) to extend the functionality of the `localStorage` global. But that's kind of besides the point.

Comment: So, this means you'd be saving the value under a key that is a string that says "Symbol(isShown)"? Then what's the advantage of using this in stead of just a key that says "isShown"?

Comment: @sjbuysse None. Which is why you should not do this.

Comment: @sjbuysse There is no advantage, but you might be using Symbols elsewhere in objects in your application that you want to then use in LocalStorage too for consistency.